# Form with ManyToMany relation switched to indirect entity with additional field

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

I've got two entities, Producer and Functionality. They are in ManyToMany relation, however I need additional field $description which will contain description for the functionality chosen by a Producer (every producer can describe the same functionality in his own words). To do so, I've created an indirect ProducerFunctionality entity (see below).

Now I have a Producer edit form (`$resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => Producer:class])`). I need to display ALL functionalities. They must be checkboxes and next to the every checkbox I need to have $description field (textarea). If producer has already any functionalities chosen (so $producerFunctionalities collection is not empty) I need to have the corresponding checkboxes checked and the $description textarea filled when rendering the form. Can Symfony form system handle that?

Here's the shorthened model:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Producer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProducerFunctionality", mappedBy="producer", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $producerFunctionalities;

    // getter, adder, remover
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ProducerFunctionality
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Producer", inversedBy="producerFunctionalities")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $producer

     /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Functionality")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
      */
     private $functionality;

     /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="text")
      */
     private $description;

    // getters and setters
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Functionality
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column
     */
    private $name;

    // getter and setter. No relation to ProducerFunctionality, because there won't be updating ProducerFunctionality from this side of realtion.
}
```